# Вывод похожих записей по тегам (несколько типов записей) wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть 3 типа записей (post, cooking, variety)
Хочу чтобы в записях выводились другие записи сooking, variety по тегам.

```
function digatalart_tag_rel_post_title(){
    global $post;
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    if($tags){
        $tag_ids = array();
        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => variety, cooking,
            'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'showposts'=>8, // Количество выводимых похожих записей.
            'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
        $my_query = new wp_query($args);
        if($my_query->have_posts()){
            echo '<div class="t-container" style="padding-top:20px;">';
            while($my_query->have_posts()){
                $my_query->the_post();
            ?>
                <div class="t405__col t-col t-col_2 t-align_left"><a class="t405__link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <div class="t405__imgbox" >
                <div class="t405__img" style="background-image: url('<?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
echo $thumb_url[0];
?>');"></div>

                         <div class="t405__separator"></div>            </div>
            <div class="t405__textwrapper">
                <div class="t405__uptitle t-uptitle" style=""><span class="t405__tag"><?php the_category(',') ?></span></div>      
                <div class="t405__title t-name" style=""><?php the_title(); ?></div>       
                <div class="t405__descr t-descr" style=""><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>            </div>
            </a>
        </div></div>
            <?php
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        else{
            echo '';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Но выводятся все записи с типа variety. Как сделать чтобы чисто по походим тегам выводились записи? неразобрался

Answer (score 0):

Строка

```
'post_type' => variety, cooking,
```

Должна быть записана в виде

```
'post_type' => array( 'variety', 'cooking' ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'showposts'=>8,
```

заменить на

```
'posts_per_page' => 8,
```

И опять же, вместо `tag__in` лучше использовать

```
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ваша таксономия',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $tag_ids,
        ),
    ),
```

Для custom post type самое то. При условии что у **variety** и **cooking** та же самая таксономия, в противном случае `'field' => 'term_id',` моно заменить на `name`, а вместо `$individual_tag->term_id;` получать `$individual_tag->name;` при условии что они одинаковые у разных таксономий.